# Can I upgrade laptop memory to 32GB of RAM?

Tags: memory, upgrade, asus-laptop

I have an [ASUS G56JK](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/G56JK/) laptop with [Intel Core i7-4710HQ](http://ark.intel.com/products/78930/Intel-Core-i7-4710HQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_50-GHz) processor which can handle up to 32GB of RAM as intel mentioned in its data sheet. But I'm not sure if I can upgrade memory to this level and I don't know if any upgrade kit of 2x16GB DDR3L could be find on market. Could anyone please tell me if it's possible or not?

Comment: I have clicked first link in your question, then the *Specifications* tab, and voila: *"DDR3L MHz SDRAM, 2 x SO-DIMM socket for expansion up to 16 GB SDRAM "*. There's no official support for 32 GB.

Comment: @gronostaj: Thanks, but is that possible to upgrade it myself or you're saying that the motherboard does not support this amount of memory at all?

Comment: It does not 16GB module support is extremely rare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to several websites ([this one](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Asus-G56JK-DH71-15.6-Intel-Core-i7-2.5GHz-12GB-DDR3-750GB-HDD-DVD-Super-Multi-Drive-Windows-8.1-64-bit/42585515), for example), your laptop can only handle up to 16 GB of ram.

Comment: Are you saying that the motherboard does not support this amount of memory at all?

Comment: Yes. This can have different reasons which mainly have to do with addressing the ram. It can be something as basic as not having enough pins. If you want to read about it, here's some link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_limit

Comment: Please limit your answers to the facts that address the question.  It really isn't appropriate to include a request for the answer to be accepted as part of the answer.  Thanks.